# Chart.js not working with Pug and Node for PDF

Tags: chart.js, pug, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to create a line chart inside a PDF file using `Chart.js`, `Node`, `Pug` and `Headless chrome (html-pdf-chrome)` and it is not working.

The rendered HTML works directly in browser, but the generated PDF is blank. Adding a timeout makes no difference with completionTrigger.

I am wondering if it is even possible to do this, and if so, where did I go wrong?

Node file:

```
const pug = require('pug');
const htmlPdf = require('html-pdf-chrome');

async function createPDF() {
    const html = pug.renderFile('template.pug', {})
    const options = {
        port: 9222,
        completionTrigger: new htmlPdf.CompletionTrigger.Timer(5000),
    };

    htmlPdf.create(html, options).then((pdf) => pdf.toFile('output.pdf'));
}

createPDF();
```

Pug template:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        title test
        script(type="text/javascript", src='chart.js')//chart.js lib
        script(type="text/javascript", src='scripts.js')

    body
        canvas#myChart(width='200' height='100' style='border:1px solid #000000;')
```

scripts file:

```
window.onload = function () {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    });
};
```